# How to pass parameters into Java method using QAndroidJniObject

Tags: java, qt, qandroidjniobject

In my Qt app, if I have a method written in Java inside my MainActivity class like below,

```
public Boolean myJavaTestMethod() {
    return true;
}
```

I know that I can invoke the method in the following way:

```
QAndroidJniObject method_retval = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod<jboolean>("myJavaTestMethod");
```

**Question:**
Above is great and it works. But, how do I pass a string from Qt C++ side into `myJavaTestMethod`?

Lets say I want to call the below method which takes an input parameter `String` into it

```
public Boolean myJavaTestMethodWithParam(String str) {
    return true;
}
```

**Environment:**
I am using Qt 5.15.1 commercial version.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the following steps:

1. Call your Java object's function using name and `signature`:

```
QAndroidJniObject result = activity.callObjectMethod("myJavaTestMethodWithParam", "(Ljava/lang/String;)B", myJString);
```

Where `activity` is just what `QtAndroid::androidActivity()` returns, `myJavaTestMethodWithParam` your activity function and  `"(Ljava/lang/String;)B"` is its signature.

2. Turn your QString into a jstring:

```
QString helloString("Hello");

QAndroidJniObject string = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(helloString);
jstring myJString = string.object<jstring>();
```

To understand the `signature` part, check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432

More on calling Android/Java methods here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html#callObjectMethod-1

Comment: Can you please add the code for how you got the `activity` object?

Comment: Oh, that's just as you did, `QtAndroid::androidActivity()`, I just left it out to save space.

Comment: This doesn't work. I think this answer is wrong. How can `activity.myJavaTestMethodWithParam` compile?

Comment: I just saw what you said, I fixed it, `myJavaTestMethodWithParam` won't compile obviously, that's the method you want to call, it goes as the first argument of `callObjectMethod(...)`. A mistake typing in the solution.